# How to get to the Golden Lane (Zlatá ulička) in Prague?

Tags: tickets, sightseeing, czech-republic, prague

I am confused whether Golden Lane (Zlatá ulička) is a regular street or a part of the Prague Castle (Pražský hrad) that can only be entered with a ticket and at certain times. I read that it is, in fact, a part of the Castle, but also just a street. I am only interested in seeing the street without buying a tour around the Castle.

Thus, my questions are:

- Is the Golden Lane a regular street or a part of the Castle?
- Is there any way to get there without purchasing an entrance ticket to the Castle? If so, is it free?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The Golden Lane is technically a street but there are only shops/exhibitions there, not actual inhabitants.
- You can enter the street [for free](http://www.kudyznudy.cz/Aktivity-a-akce/Aktivity/Zlata-ulicka-na-Prazskem-hrade.aspx) between 16:00 and 22:00, however the shops would be closed at that time. Otherwise a ticket is 250 CZK (~10 EUR)
- Actually getting to the street is easy, just follow [Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/yp5JRfJTJQQ2). There's even Street View of the whole area so you can check it out in advance.

As a person who's visited the street a few times I'd recommend going during the free hours as the interiors are not particularly interesting.

Comment: I recommend the Toy Museum which I recall is on the street but downhill from the ticket control. Largest collection of Barbie Dolls.